# How do I save a matplotlib image stretched

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am making a program, which gives me a graph of users.

But it gives me something like this after the amount of dates has grown too high.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwSdc.png

I want to save them stretched, make them longer so you will be able to see dates properly.

Is there any parameter for this in plot.savefig('name')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example this data

[image: Problem]

**Option 1**

You could rotate tick labels using:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image: solution1]

**Option 2**

or do it automaticly if you have date format:

```
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

It will print your x-axis values vertically.

Hope this helps!